# activemq dispatch messages in broker to specific subscribers

Tags: activemq-classic, messagebroker

I use activemq with spring boot.
I wanted send topic only to specific subscribers. I know that to achieve it I can specify selectors on JMSListener but this mean that I already sent message to subscriber. What I want to do is to dispatch messages on broker level. 
Currently I have below code:

```
public Broker broker() throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setBrokerName(BROKER_NAME);
    broker.addConnector(BROKER_URL);
    policy.setTopic(USER_TOPIC);
    broker.start();
    return broker.getBroker();
}
```

Let say I have messages which are able to send two subject BOOKS and FOOD. 
For subscriber A only BOOKS are available and for subscriber B BOOKS and FOOD.

Question: 
Is it possible to achieve it on broker level? If so how. I know that there is something like destination policy but I don't know how to use it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages can be routed and secured to different topic or queue destinations in a variety of ways:

1. Separate topics per subscribers (topic://BOOKS, topic://FOOD)
2. Single topic, but use a message header (topic://EVENTS)
   a. Message header "EVENT_TYPE='FOOD'"  or "EVENT_TYPE='BOOKS'"
3. You can secure the destinations so only the 'books' user can subscribe to the topic://BOOKS and only the 'food' user can subscribe to the topic://FOOD
4. Use a Virtual Topic which is publish to a topic, subscribe to a queue and get the best of all the above.  For example publish to: topic://EVENTS and then subscribe from: queue://vConsumer.BOOKS.EVENTS, queue://vConsumer.FOOD.EVENTS

Links:

- ActiveMQ Authorization: http://activemq.apache.org/security.html
- ActiveMQ Virtual Topics: http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html